# Integrate a streaming server with onvif protocol

Tags: video-streaming, gsoap, onvif

I have set a streaming server on my raspberry pi to stream my camera over the network, i can stream the camera using a url like http://ipAddress:portNumber I want to build on that to make the Camera onvif compliant, how do I proceed? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using "[rpos](https://github.com/BreeeZe/rpos)", though I have not tested with it.
The result found by "[Turn your raspberry pi into an ONVIF IP camera](https://forums.zoneminder.com/viewtopic.php?t=25392)"

There is one thing you need to know.
You should consider the device meet the "[Profile S](https://www.onvif.org/profiles/profile-s/)" for inter-operation with "Profile S" compatible ONVIF client(VMS/NVR).

The well-known ONVIF client is "[ONVIF Device Manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/onvifdm/)", also known as ONVIFDM

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, this fulfills my need for the raspberry pi, however i was looking for some implementation details with regarding the usee of gsoap and implementing ONVIF client and server.